# Use base object in child constructor (C#)

Tags: c#

I have a class which has a string ('name') and a dictionary of features ('features').
Instances are constructed by looking up the name in a file and pulling the features from there.
I am adding extra features to the dictionary elsewhere in the code.
What I would like to know is, is it possible to use an instance of the parent object in a constructor for the child?

E.g.

```
public parentClass(string name)
{
    this.name = name
    this.features = ... gets features from file ...
}

public childClass(parentClass parentObject, feature extraFeatureValue)
{
   childObject = parentObject???
   this.features[extraFeature] = extraFeatureValue
}
```

I am assuming that I should

a) have a new class for objects with extra features, so I can tell which is which

b) make the new class a child of the old one, since it's only a few extra features, and I want to keep the methods

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A previous answer (now deleted) was what I was looking for: 'copy constructors' are possible, which take as the argument another object of the same type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116(v=vs.80).aspx

So I can add one of these to the parent class, and then extend it in the child class:

```
public Animal(Animal previousAnimal)
{
    this.name = previousAnimal.name;
    this.features = previousAnimal.features;
}

public Fish(parentClass animal, bool isSaltwater)
    : base(parentClass animal)
{
   this.features[SaltWaterFish] = isSaltwater;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> What I would like to know is, is it possible to use an instance of the
>   parent object in a constructor for the child?

Yes, you can. Use the [`base`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword. Also take note that you don't need to pass the parent instance to the child constructor. The parent's default constructor will implicitly be called if you create a new `Child` instance. If you want to call a custom constructor of your base class, call the base class constructor in your child constructor. Like in the sample below.

You can also read more about constructors in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parent p = new Child();
    }
}

class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        SomeBaseProp = "BaseProperty";
    }

    public Parent(string name)
    {
        SomeBaseProp = name;
    }
    public string SomeBaseProp { get; set; }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public Child()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(base.SomeBaseProp);
    }

    public Child(string someString) : base(someString)
    {  } //this will call the custom constructor of your base class before constructing this child class

    public int SomeChildProp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to call the parent class constructor; I wanted to pass in an already-constructed parent object as an argument.
A previous answer mentioned 'copy constructors', which is what I wasn't sure existed; it seems to have been deleted now, but it was the answer I was looking for.
Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

from your code, it seems you are asking how to use your parent class constructor from your child class?

you can invoke base constructors like this:

```
public ChildClass(string name, Feature extraFeature)
:base(name) //this initializes this class with the constructor of the base class
{
    Features.Add(extraFeature); //this adds your extraFeature to the features-list.
}
```

allthough, I do struggle to fully understand your question. For instance; If this extra feature has to be passed into the contructor of ChildClass, would it not be just as good to give your parent-class an AddFeature-method?

or maybe the feature that the ChildClass has extra is always the same, in which case it is not needed as a constructor parameter?

is the name parameter the name of the class, and the list of features actually just a list of methods to call? if so; have you looked into using reflection?

Edit; My take on your situation:

```
public class FeatureObject
{
    public String Name { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<String,String> Features { get; private set; }


    public FeatureObject (string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Features = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        Features.Add("Name",name);//just an example of a feature that all objects have
    }
}

public class Fish: FeatureObject
{
    public Color Color { get; private set; }

    public Fish(String name, Color color)
    :base(name) //initializes Name and Features as described in FeatureObject-class
    {
        Features.Add("Color", color.ToString());//Adds color to the features-dictionary
    }
}
```

I still think you could do this easier.

for instance, this method will try to return a string representation of a named property in an object:

```
public static String GetPropertyValue(object o, String property)
{
    try
    {
        return o.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(o, null).ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

if you have your objects in a Dictionary Objects, you can fetch them in a method like this:

```
public static String GetPropertyValue(String objectName, String propertyName)
{
    try
    {
        var o = Objects[objectName];
        return GetPropertyValue(o, propertyName)
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.

The name parameter was the name of the object - let's say 'fish' - and the features could be things like 'size', 'colour'. (So features is a Dictionary).
Hence the extra feature is always the same feature, but could take different values.
Since the list of features is otherwise static, I wanted to have different classes for objects with the standard list of features, and objects with an extended list.

Does that seem like a reasonable way to structure it?

Comment: (Apologies for the confusion over lists and dictionaries - I'm clearly using a non-programming definition of 'list' in my head, which is not helping.)